# phpseclib3 SFTP script working locally but not working on cPanel

Tags: php, cpanel, phpseclib

I want to download a file from SFTP server using PHP 7.2 and phpseclib3. The problem is that I wrote a script that is working fine locally and downloading the file, But when I upload the code on cPanel it is not working.

**My Script (main.php)**

```php
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use phpseclib3\Net\SFTP;

$sftp = new SFTP('170.135.187.17');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
$sftp->get('/Download/Inherent.40IW.IW_DailyNAV.csv', 'Inherent.40IW.IW_DailyNAV.csv');
?>
```

I am using composer. To run it on the cPanel server I copy all the files to `public_html` folder. Then I open terminal from cPanel and navigate to `public_html` and run `composer install` and then run `php main.php` to test the script on server.

But I get `Login Failed` without any errors.

**What I tried**

I search and found that you need to bind the socket when you have shared hosting.

So I change my code to this:

```php
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use phpseclib3\Net\SFTP;


$opts = array(
    'socket' => array(
        'bindto' => '127.255.255.255:0',
    ),
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$socket = stream_socket_client('170.135.187.17:22', $errno, $errstr, ini_get('default_socket_timeout'), STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);

$sftp = new SFTP($socket);
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
$sftp->get('/Download/Inherent.40IW.IW_DailyNAV.csv', 'Inherent.40IW.IW_DailyNAV.csv');
?>
```

The above code is working locally but still not working when I upload it to cPanel.

I also tried logging the error using `$sftp->getSFTPErrors()` but it outputs empty array.

Not: If anyone has another method to download files from sftp please suggest it. Keep in mind that I donot have sudo access in cPanel.

Comment: Assuming you've set logging to this `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', SSH2::LOG_COMPLEX);`, what is the output of `$sftp->getLog()`

Comment: @Haridarshan I did not get any log after using getLog only output is Login Failed

Comment: Where have you add this line `$sftp->getLog()` in the code?

Comment: @Haridarsha 
`print_r($sftp->getLog());`
`exit('Login Failed');`

Comment: Just to ensure, have you set the logging to `SSH2::LOG_COMPLEX` in the code? Also, try to telnet sftp ip and port from your shared webserver.

Comment: @Haridarshan yes and I also test log method locally it is showing logs but it is not showing logs in cPanel terminal

Comment: In Net/SSH2.php there's this line: `$this->fsock = @fsockopen($this->host, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, $this->curTimeout == 0 ? 100000 : $this->curTimeout);`? What happens if you remove the `@`? There's also `user_error(rtrim("Cannot connect to $host. Error $errno. $errstr"));`. Maybe that's being suppressed by your PHP settings so maybe just echo that out and see if it says anything

Comment: Another thing you could try to do is to just connect to the server with `fsockopen` by itself. Sure, there's a lot more to SSH than just fsockopen but if you can't even connect with fsockopen then phpseclib isn't going to be able to connect either. This would help you hone in on the problem area and eliminate the phpseclib code as a causative issue.

Comment: @QasimMehdi Have you tried logging to sftp server directly from the server? please check once. If you're not able to login to sftp server directly from your server, then you'll need to contact your hosting provider as the firewall might be blocking it